# module 'pyomo' has no attribute 'AbstractModel'

Tags: python, pyomo

I have installed pyomo and trying to create a instance model from AbstractModel as follows:

import pyomo as pmo

absmd = pmo.AbstractModel()
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    absmd = pmo.AbstractModel()

But i am getting the following error:

AttributeError: module 'pyomo' has no attribute 'AbstractModel'

Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the wrong stuff. Either use `pmo.environ.AbstractModel()` or

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()
```

Comment: Thanks Joost. Worked.